# INI file with doxygen

Tags: doxygen, ini, doxywizard

My requirement is to display the contents of INI file in plain text format using doxygen. INI configuration file contains key, value pair. 
eg.

### sample INI file

[data configuration file]
key=value
Can anyone help to get the solution of above problem

Comment: It's not really clear what you need.

Comment: I am working on java project which contains INI file as well. I have documented java section but INI file is not even displaying in file structure (as part of doxygen html report). After adding *.ini in FILE_PATTERN, now ini file is visible under file structure, but content is still not visible. Please let me know what parameters I need to modify in doxygen configuration file to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  Reading the special command documentation would be recommended.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbinclude